# Ubuntu shows other users are logged in whenever I shut down even though I am the only logged in user

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, users

I just dual booted ubuntu 20.04. Whenever I try to shut down my laptop ubuntu shows that other users are logged in and shows my name in the logged in users. This happens every time i try to power off. How do I fix this?

[image]

Edit: Adding output of who , last|head command

[image]

Comment: Cancel the shutdown and use the `who` and `last|head` commands to see the logins. Please paste the outputs of these commands to your original question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Hi @FedonKadifeli .. Apologies for such a late update. My ubuntu stopped working a few days after I added this question. I just got time now to fix issues with my ubuntu. Still i have this issue whenever I try to shut down my laptop. I have added the output of the commands in my question.

Comment: What this is showing is that your ubuntu OS has not shutdown.  Try shutting down the computer from the ubuntu OS and see if it clears this up.

Comment: I have the same problem. My shutdown option is availlable and I also am the only user shown with 'who'. Running 21.10.

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: I believe you installed something that keep it live.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was because I have set up the Google Chrome desktop. After I stopped the remote server through `systemctl`, the problem is solved.

Similarly to [Fergusmac's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1663771) in Super User's [How do I stop chrome remote desktop on Unix or prevent it running on startup?](https://superuser.com/questions/1663763/how-do-i-stop-chrome-remote-desktop-on-unix-or-prevent-it-running-on-startup/1663771#1663771), I found the daemon (`chrome-remote-desktop@MY_USER_NAME`) with:

```sh
systemctl status
```

and disabled it with:

```sh
systemctl disable chrome-remote-desktop@MY_USER_NAME
```

I hope it would save someone's time.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running NoMachine Server?

https://forums.nomachine.com/topic/other-users-are-logged-in-when-i-power-off-or-restart-centos-7

I've experienced this; stopping the NoMachine server before I shutdown resolves the problem.

Comment: That was my case too.