# Ubuntu 20.04 shows "other users are logged in" whenever I attempt to shut down my computer although I'm the only one who is logged in

Tags: shutdown

I want to know if it is normal to be notified that other users are logged in when I attempt to shut down the computer.

If not, how do I solve this issue? I found a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1343872/ubuntu-shows-other-users-are-logged-in-whenever-i-shut-down-even-though-i-am-the), but I did not find an answer on this question.

[image: other users are Logged in" message like in this image]

When I check for users currently logged in, I found I'm the only user.

[image: screenshot of terminal]